# Insert Multiple Data into Database with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, database, laravel

I'm trying to insert multiple data into my database by using array and javascript. But what happened is, I only could submit one data into my complaints table. The balanced is not inserted. There is no error appeared.

**users table**

```
id
role
email
typable_id
typable_type
```

**buyers table**

```
id 
name
buyer_id
address
phone_no
```

**defects table**

```
id
name
```

**complaints table**

```
id
defect_id
image
description
report_by
```

**ComplaintController.php**

```
class ComplaintController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('buyers.complaint');
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        if (count($request->defect_id) > 0) {
            foreach($request->defect_id as $item=>$v) {
                $data = array(
                    'defect_id' => $request->defect_id[$item],
                    'image' => $request->image[$item],
                    'description' => $request->description[$item],
                    'report_by' => auth()->user()->typable->buyer_id
                );

                Complaint::insert($data);
            }
        }
        return redirect('/report-form')->with('success','Your report is submitted!');
    }
```

**complaint.blade.php**

```
<div class="panel-heading">
   <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Make New Report</strong></h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
   <div>
      <div class="panel">
         <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><center>Type of Defect</center></th>
                <th><center>Image</center></th>
                <th><center>Description</center></th>
                <th><center>Action</center></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">
                   <form action="/report-create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   {{ csrf_field() }}
                   <select class="form-control" name="defect_id[]">
                   <option value="" selected>Choose Defect</option>
                       @foreach(App\Defect::all() as $defect)
                       <option value="{{$defect->id}}">{{$defect->name}}</option>
                       @endforeach
                   </form>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                   <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="image[]">
                </td>
                <td width="45%">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]">
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="add-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
   <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></center>
</div>
```

**javascript in blade**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#add-btn').on('click',function () {
            var html = '';
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td><select class="form-control" name="defect_id[]"><option value="" selected>Choose Defect</option>@foreach(App\Defect::all() as $defect)<option value="{{$defect->id}}">{{$defect->name}}</option>@endforeach</td>';
            html += '<td><input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="image[]"></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]"></td>';
            html += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="remove-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            $('tbody').append(html);
        })
    });

    $(document).on('click','#remove-btn',function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you are appending to the `tbody` which is outside the form

Comment: Yup, put your opening form tag before the opening table tag and your closing form tag after your closing table tag. Also, your submit button should probably be in that form tag too, unless you're catching that click and submitting manually somewhere...

Comment: Though, I wonder if `<form action="/report-create"` isnt a separate form altogether and you're submitting this request via ajax or in a different form that wraps all this html but wasnt shown....

Comment: Thanks guys. I didn't notice that I misplaced the codes. It fixed now.